# unsupported pixel format type xcode

Tags: xcode

hi guys i am trying to extract frames from my camera and I am using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and here is my settings and i try to set my pixelformatTyoe as kCVPixelFormatType_24BGR

```
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoDataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[videoDataOutput setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_24BGR], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil]];
[videoDataOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
[videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:sessionQueue];
```

However, when i run the code i receive the following error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:] - 24BG (842285639) is not a supported pixel format type.  See AVCaptureOutput.h for a list of supported formats.  Available pixel format types on this platform are (
420v,
420f,
BGRA
```

).'

Does it mean that i can only use kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA? it does not make sense to me that i must create an alpha channel.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you think this question is correctly tagged?

Comment: well it might not be the best tag and i am sorry if i have tagged it wrongly..but yeah if u have any advice to my question please give your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check **availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes** from **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput**

```
availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes
Indicates the supported video pixel formats that can be specified in videoSettings
```

[Please, go through apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutput/1387050-availablevideocvpixelformattypes)